# Run text search on unwinded documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
{
    "strings" : [
        "Hello world",
        "Error connecting to server",
        "Dbus error"
    ],
    "file" : "test.c"
}
{
    "strings" : [
        "Could not configure supporting library.",
        "Assertion failed",
        "Error in server response"
    ],
    "file" : "run.c"
}
...
```

There are ~250k such documents, each having its own array of strings and a unique file name. At query time, I have a string which can be a sub-string of one of the strings of one of the docs, or can contain some of the strings from some of the docs (i.e. it will never match exactly, any of the strings from any document). 
Examples:

```
Hello world hi there             // Should match test.c
Error connecting                 // test.c
Error connecting to server: 107  // test.c
Assertion failed: Dbus error     // Should match both test.c and run.c
```

I need to retrieve the document whose "strings" field contains a string that matches the most with my query string.

I have tried indexed text search:

```
db.testcoll.find( { $text: { $search: "Could not configure supporting library." } } , {"file": 1, "_id": 0, score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
```

However, the problem with this is that there can be a document having several strings that partially match my query string, so the document having the closest matching string still gets a lower match score compared to the other document.

I tried unwinding the 'strings' field in aggregation, so that each document will have only one string and I'd expect the closest matching one to get the highest score. However, mongodb only allows a `$match` having a `$text` if it's the first pipeline stage so I couldn't have the unwind step before the it.

```
db.testcoll.aggregate([{$project: {file: 1, strings: 1}}, {$unwind: "$strings"}, {$match: { $text: { $search: "Could not configure supporting library." } }}])
```

Output:

```
2019-05-27T11:36:56.671+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage",
    "code" : 17313,
    "codeName" : "Location17313"
} : aggregate failed
```

Is there a way to perform text search on the documents returned by unwind? If not, is there any way to perform this kind of a text search in mongodb?
Thanks in advance for any help.